# query builder using 'whereNotIn' throws error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I'm trying to fetch records with an array of exceptions, here's what I tried (refer below)

```
$users_nowishlist = DB::table('employee')
    ->join('users', 'users.employee_id', '=', 'employee.employee_id')
    ->where('has_wishlist', '=', "0")
    ->whereNotIn('employee_id', ['MMMFLB003', 'guest_01', 'guest_02', 'guest_03'])
    ->where('employment_status', '=', 'ACTIVE')
    ->get();
```

so in this line was my records filter, means only records that does not equal to any of those 'employee_id' from the exceptions array will be return (refer below)

```
->whereNotIn('employee_id', ['MMMFLB003', 'guest_01', 'guest_02', 'guest_03'])
```

but instead I got this error (refer below):

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column
>   'employee_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from
>   `employee` inner join `users` on `users`.`employee_id` =
>   `employee`.`employee_id` where `has_wishlist` = 0 and `employee_id`
>   not in (MMMFLB003, guest_01, guest_02, guest_03) and
>   `employment_status` = ACTIVE)

any ideas, help please?

Comment: just change your whereNotIn to this:  `->whereNotIn('employee.employee_id', ['MMMFLB003', 'guest_01', 'guest_02', 'guest_03'])`

Comment: ow great! it works like charm, thank you! can you post your answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you are doing the join there are two columns with the same name.

That's why on your join you prefix the `employee_id` with `users.` and `employee.`

Now on your `whereNotIn` you also have to prefix it, so the query engine knows which table column you are trying to reference. So you only have to add the prefix in your `whereNotIn` clause:

```
->whereNotIn('employee.employee_id', ['MMMFLB003', 'guest_01', 'guest_02', 'guest_03'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
->whereNotIn('employee.employee_id', ['MMMFLB003', 'guest_01', 'guest_02'])
```

when using join , these errors are expected if you have two fields have the same name in the tables you join between, so always try to fetch them like this

```
table_name.field_name
```